# Should I put UseForwardedHeaders() behind a configuration flag?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In order to support running my ASP.NET Core application on Linux with a reverse proxy (nginx in this case), I had to add the following code snippet:

```
// Forward headers in order to be able to operate behind a reverse proxy
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

// The above does not appear to be enough to get the right redirect URI result when
// logging in with OpenID Connect. This code snippet from
// https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/2384 fixed it.
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(XForwardedPathBase, out StringValues pathBase))
    {
        context.Request.PathBase = new PathString(pathBase);
    }

    if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(XForwardedProto, out StringValues proto))
    {
        context.Request.Protocol = proto;
    }

    return next();
});
```

I'm unable to find any definite advice on whether I can leave this enabled by default, or if I should put this behind some explicit configuration flag?

It seems to me that this could be used to have strange effects if these headers were added when a reverse proxy isn't being used? I can't think of a way it could be exploited, but perhaps I'm missing something.

So, is there an advantage to introducing a flag for this specific piece of configuration, aside from a very minor performance improvement perhaps?

Comment: iirc it's implicitly called inside `CreateDefaultBuilder` (used to be `.UseIISIntegration()` which is iirc called within `CreateDefaultBuilder`. Also you only need it for reverse proxy scenarios to get the original protocol and the original callers ip / host name

Comment: It's only called implicitly for the IIS scenario.

Comment: context.Request.Protocol is not the right field for x-forwarded-proto, it should be scheme, and that should already be covered for you by UseForwardedHeaders.

Comment: @Tratcher Upon rechecking, I didn't need the workaround at all anymore; at least for my current hosting scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't leave this in without a reverse proxy, it's dangerous. Clients could use it to provide false values (spoofing) and trick any app logic you have that checks these values.

Comment: Yeah, I figured... Except that the application itself currently doesn't have any logic that cares either way. Still, I've introduced configuration through `appsettings.json` to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

By default `ForwardedHeadersMiddleware` allows only the loopback address as a proxy server. As in "nginx should be installed on the same machine". It will ignore headers coming from other addresses.

So it's more or less safe to add this middleware without any configuration flag. UNLESS you touch `KnownProxies` and `KnownNetworks` properties of the `options` object.

More info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0